# Передача элементов из одного XML документа в другой

Tags: xml, c#

Подскажите кто-нибудь. Имеется 2 xml файла, один содержит список клиентов, другой - список книг. Хочу сделать так, чтобы при вводе имени клиента с консоли проходила проверка xml файла на существование данного имени и, если имя существует, добавление всех данныч клиента в др. xml файл, включая город, паспортные данные, номер телефона.

```
namespace Library
{
class ClientBook
{
    //static string pathXmlClientBook= ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["XmlDataPath"].ToString();
    static string pathXmlBook = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["XmlData"].ToString();
    static string pathXmlClient = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["pathXmlData"].ToString();

    public static bool GetClientBook(Man existMan, string message)//возвращаем людей
    {
        //Открываем FileStream  
        //FileStream fsClientBook = new FileStream(pathXmlClientBook, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite); //указываем путь к файлу.
        FileStream fsBook = new FileStream(pathXmlBook, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        FileStream fsClient = new FileStream(pathXmlClient, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        //Создаем Xml документ.
        XmlDataDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDataDocument();
        //xmlDoc.Load(fsClientBook); //загружаем в память данные из файла xml
        xmlDoc.Load(fsBook);
        xmlDoc.Load(fsClient);

        ArrayList nameClient_nameBook = new ArrayList();
        string temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
        {
            temp = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[i].SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText +
                " " + xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[i].SelectSingleNode("surName").InnerText +
                " " + xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[i].SelectSingleNode("nameBook").InnerText;
            nameClient_nameBook.Add(temp);
        }
        //fsClientBook.Close();
        fsBook.Close();
        fsClient.Close();

        //Добавление элементов из одного xml файла в другой
        string viborName, viborSurName;
        viborName = Console.ReadLine();
        viborSurName = Console.ReadLine();

        //проверка на существование файла
        for (int i = 0; i < xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
        {
            if (viborName == xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[i].SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText &&
                viborSurName == xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[i].SelectSingleNode("surName").InnerText)
            {
                FileStream fsClientBook = new FileStream(pathXmlClientBook, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
                try
                {
                    using (fsClientBook)
                    {
                        xmlDoc.Load(fsClientBook);

                  //код передачи из одного XML в другой XML

                        fsClientBook.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    message = "Не удалось создать персону";
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Книга не может быть добавлена");
                }
            }
            return true;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: А что не получается?

Comment: Код не читал, но посоветовал бы посмотреть в сторону баз данных.

Comment: C помощью LinQ можно загрузить оба документа как XDocument, затем сформировать третий и перезаписать все это куда следует. У тебя же это практически реализовано.

Answer (score 3):

```
int i, l;
DataTable personal_table = new DataTable();
DataTable out_table = new DataTable("Client");
personal_table.ReadXml("откуда добавить.xml");
out_table.ReadXml("куда добавить.xml");
int index=-1;
for (i = 0; i < personal_table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (l = 0; l < out_table.Rows.Count; l++)
    {
        if (personal_table.Rows[i]["name"].ToString() == out_table.Rows[l]["name"].ToString()) index=i;
    }
}
if (index>-1)
{
    out_table.Rows.Add();
    for (i = 0; i < personal_table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        out_table.Rows[out_table.Rows.Count - 1][personal_table.Columns[i].ColumnName] = personal_table.Rows[index][i];
    }
    out_table.WriteXml("куда добавить_новый.xml");

}
```

Ну, внимательно разбираться было в лом, вы уж извиняйте, но насколько я понял, нужно что-то типа этого.

Только надо Вам будет посмотреть, как загружаются иксэмэлины. Они скорее всего зарузятся в несколько таблиц, поэтому используйте DataSet, в отладке посмотрите, какие там таблицы, а потом из датасета возьмите нужную таблицу. Примерно вот так:

```
DataSet dset = new DataSet();
dset.ReadXml("file.xml");
DataTable load_table = dset.Tables["название таблицы"];
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас выдано очень уж много лишнего кода, так что читать его целиком нет сил :)

Я не могу сказать с уверенностью (не знаю, придерживались ли MS каких-то стандартов или нет.. запросто может оказаться, что нет), но по идее добавлять элементы из одного документа в другой напрямую нельзя. Например, в W3C DOM для этого прдусмотрен метод [importNode](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#Core-Document-importNode). В противном случае, попытка вставки элкмента из чудого документа заканчивается неудачей.

**UPD**
В .NET тоже есть [importNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode.aspx). Его и следует использовать.

Comment: А возможно с помощью LINQ передать элементы из одного xml документа в другой xml документ, если возможно можете подсказать как в моем случае сделать?

Comment: Просто по заданию нельзя использовать БД и соответственно ADO.NET. Делать только в консоли.

Comment: Про LINQ, к сожалению, ничего сказать не могу. но, по идее, ничто не мешает его использовать..

Answer (score 0):

Получилось заносить ВСЕ данные о ВСЕХ персонах из одного xml файла в другой xml таким способом, но мне надо занести все данные только об одной персоне, имя и фамилию которой ввожу с клавиатуры, т.е. я ввожу имя и фамилию персоны с консоли, которая имеется в первом xml файле, а в второй xml файл попадает Имя, фамилия и остальные данные, которые имеются в первом xml файле об этой персоне, в частности паспортные данные, город и номер телефона. Может кто-нибудь, что-нибудь еще посоветут, если не трудно.

```
namespace Library
{
    class ClientBook
    {
    static string pathXmlClientBook= ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["XmlDataPath"].ToString();
    static string pathXmlBook = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["XmlData"].ToString();
    static string pathXmlClient = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["pathXmlData"].ToString();

    public static bool GetClientBook()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public static void CallClientBook()
    {
        Man newMan = new Man();

        Console.Write("\nВведите имя: ");
        newMan.Name = Console.ReadLine(); //вводим имя с клавиатуры
        Console.Write("Введите фамилию: ");
        newMan.SurName = Console.ReadLine();

        ClientBook.AddClientBook(newMan);

    }
    public static bool AddClientBook(Man newMan)
    {

        if (!checkExistClientBook(newMan))
        {
            return false;
        }
        XmlDocument xmlClientBook;
        FileStream fsClientBook = new FileStream(pathXmlClientBook, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

        try
        {
            using (fsClientBook)
            {
                xmlClientBook = new XmlDocument();
                xmlClientBook.Load(fsClientBook);
                fsClientBook.Close();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            //Создаем xml документ
            XmlDocument XmlClient = new XmlDocument();
            XmlElement newClientBook;//создаем новый элемент тега Man
            XmlElement newOuterClientBook = xmlClientBook.CreateElement("Man");

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvpCB in newMan.ManInfo)
            {
                newClientBook = xmlClientBook.CreateElement(kvpCB.Key); //создали первый тег по имени name
                newClientBook.InnerText = kvpCB.Value;
                newOuterClientBook.AppendChild(newClientBook);
            }
            xmlClientBook.DocumentElement.InsertAfter(newOuterClientBook, xmlClientBook.DocumentElement.LastChild); //закрывающийся тег Man
            //Открытие xml файла в который надо занести информацию из другого xml файла
            FileStream writerCB = new FileStream(pathXmlClientBook,
                FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            xmlClientBook.Save(writerCB);
            writerCB.Dispose();
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static bool checkExistClientBook(Man newMan)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlClientBook = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDocument XmlClient;
        try
        {
            //Создание xml документа с клиентами
            XmlClient = new XmlDocument();
            XmlClient.Load(pathXmlClient);
        }
        catch
        {
            return true; //считаем, что такая персона уже есть
        }
        XmlNodeList xmlListName = XmlClient.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("name");
        XmlNodeList xmlListsurName = XmlClient.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("surName");

            for (int j = 0; j < xmlListName.Count; j++)
                //Проверка имени ввода с клавиатуры и в xml файле
        if (xmlListName[j].InnerText == newMan.ManInfo["name"] &&
            xmlListsurName[j].InnerText == newMan.ManInfo["surName"])

            {
                //Залезаем в корень xml файла и добавляем людей
                XmlNode root = XmlClient.DocumentElement;
                XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode(string.Format(
                    "Man[name='{0}' and surName='{1}']",
                    newMan.Name, newMan.SurName));
                    XmlNode outer = node.ParentNode; //нахождение родительского тега
                    outer.AppendChild(node);
                    XmlClient.Save(pathXmlClientBook);

                    return true;

            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Получилось передавть данные из одного xml файла в другой с использованием xPath таким образом. Может кому интересно будет:

```
 namespace Library
{

class ClientBook
{
    public static void CallClientBook()
    {
        Man newMan = new Man();

        Console.Write("\nВведите имя: ");
        newMan.Name = Console.ReadLine(); //вводим имя с клавиатуры
        Console.Write("Введите фамилию: ");
        newMan.SurName = Console.ReadLine();

        ClientBook.Test(newMan);
    }

    static string pathXmlClientBook = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["XmlDataPath"].ToString();
    static string pathXmlBook = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["XmlData"].ToString();
    static string pathXmlClient = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["pathXmlData"].ToString();

    public static Man Test()
    { return null; }

    public static Man Test(Man newMan)
    {
        Man man = new Man();

        XPathDocument xpdoc = new XPathDocument(pathXmlClient);

        XPathNavigator nav = xpdoc.CreateNavigator();

        XPathNodeIterator iterator = nav.Select(string.Format("Client/Man[name='{0}' and surName='{1}']",
            newMan.Name, newMan.SurName));

        if (iterator.Count != 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Такого клиента в БД нет!");
            return man;
        }

        iterator.MoveNext();
        XPathNodeIterator innerIterator = iterator.Current.SelectChildren(XPathNodeType.Element);

        while (innerIterator.MoveNext())
            man.ManInfo[innerIterator.Current.Name] = innerIterator.Current.Value;

            XmlDocument xmlClientBook = new XmlDocument();
            XmlDocument XmlClient = new XmlDocument();
            FileStream fsClientBook = new FileStream(pathXmlClientBook, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

            try
            {
                using (fsClientBook)
                {
                    xmlClientBook = new XmlDocument();
                    xmlClientBook.Load(fsClientBook);

                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return man;
            }

            try
            {
                //Создаем xml документ

                XmlElement newClientBook;//создаем новый элемент тега Man
                XmlElement newOuterClientBook = xmlClientBook.CreateElement("Man");

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvpCB in man.ManInfo)
                {
                    newClientBook = xmlClientBook.CreateElement(kvpCB.Key); //создали первый тег по имени name
                    newClientBook.InnerText = kvpCB.Value;
                    newOuterClientBook.AppendChild(newClientBook);
                }
                //Вставка нового узла
                xmlClientBook.DocumentElement.InsertAfter(newOuterClientBook, xmlClientBook.DocumentElement.LastChild); //закрывающийся тег Man

                //Открытие xml файла в который надо занести информацию из другого xml файла
                FileStream writerCB = new FileStream(pathXmlClientBook,
                    FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
                xmlClientBook.Save(writerCB);
                writerCB.Dispose();
            }
            catch
            {
                return man;
            }

            return man;
        }

    }
}
```